# Is C a part of the .NET framework?

Tags: c++, c, .net

I've searched the net for this, but I couldn't really find an answer. I've found this though: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875057.aspx

It says that C++ is a part of the .NET framework, and the headline writes "C/C++", but there wasn't much about C, so I wasn't able to understand if it is or not.

Comment: I wouldn't say that C or C++ is part of the .net framework - but that the framework would support them

Comment: No. The .NET Framework is a bunch of classes(libraries) abstracting some lower-level windows functionality. C and C++ are languages.

Comment: OK, so does that mean that I can use C in the .NET framework (with C# libraries for example)?

Comment: Yes you can. But I would go with C#... C++ in the worst case.

Comment: C++ is not a part of .NET. Managed C++ is, and I am not sure if that can be called C++ in the first place.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in the worst case'? Is it preferred to use a different language like VB?

Comment: .NET is analogous to JVM.  Microsoft's preferred languages for .NET are:  C#, VB.NET, and F#.  There are other languages that target .NET, just as there are languages like Kotlin, Clojure, and Scala that target JVM.  Getting C or C++ to interoperate with .NET is not easy, and unless you have a Really Good Reason, is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: The link you give is for C and C++ with Visual Studio, but *not* for .NET. Microsoft has *yet another language*, confusingly called C++/CLI, that is for .NET. See [.NET Programming with C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp). As far as I know, people only use that when they *have to*. Otherwise use C# if you want .NET

Comment: Microsoft has also made it quite clear in online postings that they do not intend to support modern C language features that are not present in C++, so they don't really even make a modern C compiler. They make a compiler for a C-like language that is a subset of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework is an object oriented programming framework meant to be used with languages that it provides bindings for. Since C is not an object oriented language it wouldn't make sense to use it with the framework. Microsoft does provide [its own version of C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) (that is incompatible with standard C++) to be used with the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are both low level, you can always write code in C and C++ that would work with other languages. The main language for the .NET I think is C#. I don't think it's necessary for you to write C++ code for a .NET project. And if you had to, then you wouldn't need to ask this, because you would know that your question doesn't even make sense. Of course, since you don't know your question is ok.

So in a sense, [c](/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) are part of everything, and you can always write code in low level languages with interfaces for higher level ones like [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) with [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) support. But that is quite specialized and is rarely needed.